# App icon missing for iPhone 7 and 8

Tags: ios, iphone, appicon

App icon image is missing for iPhone 7 and 8. For rest of the devices app icon is shown. I have tried various solution available but I am not able to find any result for this bug. Please check the following screen shots for OPG.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try restarting the phones / simulators.

Comment: I try it many times but still getting this issue

Comment: No, Can you please explain on how to use UI test

Comment: Don't worry about it, I was looking at the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your 
`Info.plist` ( Remove~ipad )

For xml view use this

```
<key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
<array>
    <string>icon.png</string>
    <string>icon2.png</string>
    <string>icon3.png</string>
    <string>icon4.png</string>
</array>
```

[image]

Also if you are using assets catlogue :

Your AppIcon must look like this

[image]

Comment: I have updated my question and AppIcon asset looks like above mentioned image. I am unable to find CFBundleIconFilter in Info plist. I am using XCode 9

Comment: Please check my edit and find the xml.
Don't worry about autocomplete if you are using Property List just paste this  CFBundleIconFiles and hit enter an array will be created means you are on right track.

Comment: I am still facing this issue even after applying your way.

Comment: found your solution?

Comment: Yes, I just create a new App icon asset and it works fine for iPhone 6. But its not working in simulator. It works only for devices.

Comment: Great!! Weird though :)

Comment: Yes, I try to reset simulator but still icon is missing.